# Utilizando ng-view e routeProvider não renderiza o partial html

Tags: angularjs, route, angular-routes

Estou iniciando no AngularJS e não consigo fazer as rotas com $routeProvider funcionar de jeito nenhum. Já busquei várias tentativas de solução no google e nenhuma delas resolveu o meu problema.

Simplesmente a partial não é carregada no ng-view da index.html.

Segue o meu código (como o problema é no route, acredito que não seja necessário colocar o código do controller ou do serviço).

app.js :

```js
var app = angular.module("appGame", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(
   function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
           templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
           controller: 'usuarioController',
           controllerAs: "loginCtrl"
         })
       .otherwise({
           redirectTo: '/'
        });
   });
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appGame">
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/site.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <div ng-view></div>    
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        
        <script src="style/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="style/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.js"></script>  
 <script src="app/services/serviceLogin.js"></script>
 <script src="app/controller/usuarioController.js"></script>    
 </body>
</html>
```

login.html

```html
<div class="col-md-8"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
 <h4>Realize o Login abaixo:</h4>
 <form name="formLogin" ng-submit="formLogin.$valid && loginCtrl.realizaLogin()">
  <div role="alert" ng-show="mostraMensagem" ng-class="classeErro">
   {{mensagemErro}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Login</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" placeholder="Login" ng-model="loginCtrl.usuarioLogin.login" required>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Senha" ng-model="loginCtrl.usuarioLogin.senha" required>
    </div>
  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Login</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

usuarioController.js

```js
var ggApp = angular.module('appGame', ['servicoLogin']);

ggApp.controller("usuarioController", ['$scope', 'Login', function($scope, Login) {
  
 $scope.erro = false;
 $scope.mostraMensagem = false;
 $scope.mensagemErro = "teste";
 $scope.classeErro ='alert alert-danger'
 
 this.usuarioLogin = {};
 
 $scope.setClasseErro = function() {
  
  if ($scope.erro) {
   $scope.classeErro ='alert alert-danger'
  } else {
   $scope.classeErro = 'alert alert-success'
  }
 };
 
 this.realizaLogin = function() {
  
  var usuario = {
    email: this.usuarioLogin.login,
    senha: this.usuarioLogin.senha
  }
  
  var promise = Login.login(usuario);
  
  promise.$promise.then( 
    function success(usuario) {
     if (usuario.id > 0) {
      $scope.erro = false;
      $scope.mensagemErro = "Usuário encontrado com código = " + usuario.id;
     } else {
      $scope.erro = true;
      $scope.mensagemErro = "Usuário não encontrado!";
     };
     $scope.mostraMensagem = true;
     $scope.setClasseErro();
     
    },
    function error(value) {
     $scope.erro = true;
     $scope.mostraMensagem = true;
     $scope.mensagemErro = "Erro: " + value.status;
    }
  );
 };
}]);
```

serviceLogin.js

```js
var servicoLogin = angular.module('servicoLogin', ['ngResource']);

servicoLogin.factory('Login', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost:8081/GamerAppService/webserver/usuario/realizaLogin', {}, {
      login: {method:'POST'}
    });
  }]);
```

A estrutura de diretórios é:

--app
---app.js
---controller
----usuarioController.js
---services
----serviceLogin.js
--views
---login.html
-index.html

Comment: O console do navegador apresenta algum erro?

Comment: Nenhum erro Vinicius. Console está limpo e é o que mais me intriga.

Comment: Você esta usando caminhos relativos em quase todas as URLs de scripts e inclusive das views e templates... altere por caminhos absolutos (provavelmente só adicionar o "/" no início das URLs deve resolver). Talvez possa ser algo relacionado, pois não vejo outro motivo. Outra coisa, altere a chamada ao método `config` para passar um vetor ao invés de uma função, tal qual é feito com os controllers, aonde se especifica as dependências dele na ordem esperada pela função, que é o último elemento do vetor.

Comment: @Vinicius, fiz as alterações sugeridas, mas continuo com o mesmo problema. O mais estranho de tudo é que quando eu coloco o /login, por exemplo, na url do browser ele me retorna um 404, ou seja, parece que ele não está processando a configuração de rotas.

Comment: Hoje a noite terei acesso a um servidor web, e vou tentar simular o problema. Te mando notícias!

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira acho que consegui descobrir o ponto do problema, mas não encontrei ainda a solução. Fui fazendo um teste por exclusão e quando retirei a referência ao meu controller, o route funcionou. Fiz um teste colocando o controller dentro do app.js e funcionou também. Só não funciona com o controller em arquivo separado! Aproveitei pra colocar o código do controller na pergunta pra ver se tem alguma coisa errada nele que está causando esse problema (continua não apresentando erro no console).

Comment: Vou arriscar uma outra possibilidade... se não me engano [estou no serviço, sem tempo para pesquisar] quando os scripts são colocados no `body`, eles não são executados na ordem que aparecem. Se você colocá-los no `head`, funciona?

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira, não funciona. Eu só consegui fazer funcionar com arquivos separadas tirando o var ggApp = angular.module('appGame', ['servicoLogin']); do arquivo do controller e colocando a injeção direto no app.js. Parece que ele, de alguma forma, estava sobrescrevendo o app com o que estava na controller.

Comment: Não acredito que não havia percebido isso... realmente, esta errado. Se você quer utilizar o mesmo módulo declarado anteriormente, nas reutilizações passe apenas 1 parâmetro para a chamada `angular.module`. Ou seja, a primeira chamada pode especificar dependências do seu módulo no segundo parâmetro. Nas demais chamadas, você não pode especificar o parâmetro das dependências (ele tem que ser `undefined`).